# Efficient method to filter and add based on certain conditions (3 conditions in this case)

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, dplyr, subset-sum

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
     a    b    c   d
     1    1    1   0
     1    1    1   200
     1    1    1   300
     1    1    2   0
     1    1    2   600
     1    2    3   0
     1    2    3   100
     1    2    3   200
     1    3    1   0
```

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
     a    b    c   d
     1    1    1   250
     1    1    2   600
     1    2    3   150
     1    3    1   0
```

I am currently doing it 
     {

```
  n=nrow(subset(Wallmart, a==i &    b==j & c==k  ))
  sum=subset(Wallmart, a==i &    b==j & c==k  )
  #sum
  sum1=append(sum1,sum(sum$d)/(n-1))
```

}

I would like to add the 'd' coloumn and take the average by counting the number of rows without counting 0. For example the first row is (200+300)/2 = 250.
Currently I am building a list that stores the 'd' coloumn but ideally I want it in the format above. For example first row would look like

```
     a    b    c   d
     1    1    1   250
```

This is a very inefficient way to do this work. The code takes a long time to run in a loop.
so any help is appreciated that makes it run faster. The original data frame has about a million rows.

Comment: ...and what precisely are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't see a loop. There seems to be something missing from your question. Anyway, never use `append` in a loop.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question, now it should be easy to understand. Thank You.

Comment: @user2575429, I have updated my answer following your edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(d ~ a + b + c, data = df, sum)
#   a b c   d
# 1 1 1 1 500
# 2 1 3 1   0
# 3 1 1 2 600
# 4 1 2 3 300
```

As noted by @Roland, for bigger data sets, you may try `data.table` or `dplyr` instead, e.g.:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(a, b, c) %>%
  summarise(
    sum_d = sum(d))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# Groups: a, b
# 
#   a b c sum_d
# 1 1 1 1   500
# 2 1 1 2   600
# 3 1 2 3   300
# 4 1 3 1     0
```

**Edit** following updated question.
If you want to calculate group-wise mean, excluding rows that are zero, you may try this:

```
aggregate(d ~ a + b + c, data = df, function(x) mean(x[x > 0]))
#   a b c   d
# 1 1 1 1 250
# 2 1 3 1 NaN
# 3 1 1 2 600
# 4 1 2 3 150

df %>%
  filter(d != 0) %>%
  group_by(a, b, c) %>%
  summarise(
    mean_d = mean(d))

#   a b c mean_d
# 1 1 1 1    250
# 2 1 1 2    600
# 3 1 2 3    150
```

However, because it seems that you wish to treat your zeros as missing values rather than numeric zeros, I think it would be better to convert them to `NA` when preparing your data set, *before* the calculations.

```
df$d[df$d == 0] <- NA
df %>%
  group_by(a, b, c) %>%
  summarise(
    mean_d = mean(d, na.rm = TRUE))

#   a b c mean_d
# 1 1 1 1    250
# 2 1 1 2    600
# 3 1 2 3    150
# 4 1 3 1    NaN
```

Comment: +1 But for a million observations data.table or dplyr might be preferable.

Comment: @Roland, Thanks for your comment! I added a `dplyr` alternative.

Comment: Thank You @Henrik, specially for answering after edit.

Answer (score 3):

This is the `data.table` solution per your last edit.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(df)[, if(any(d[d > 0])) mean(d[d > 0]) else 0, by = c("a","b","c")]
# a b c  V1
# 1: 1 1 1 250
# 2: 1 1 2 600
# 3: 1 2 3 150
# 4: 1 3 1   0
```

## Edit #2:

@Arun suggestion to speed it up

```
setDT(df)[, mean(d[d > 0]), by = c("a","b","c")][is.nan(V1), V1 := 0]
```

## Edit #3

@eddis suggestion

```
setDT(df)[, sum(d) / pmax(1, sum(d > 0)), by = list(a, b, c)]
```

Comment: Thank You David for suggesting the alternative method. NaN is not an issue I will fix it.

Comment: this is a little faster: `setDT(df)[, sum(d) / pmax(1, sum(d > 0)), by = list(a, b, c)]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

Step1: Setup data table:

```
df <- read.table(text="     a    b    c   d
     1    1    1   0
     1    1    1   200
     1    1    1   300
     1    1    2   0
     1    1    2   600
     1    2    3   0
     1    2    3   100
     1    2    3   200
     1    3    1   0",header=T)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setkey(df,a,b,c)
```

Step2: Do the computation:

```
df[,sum(d)/ifelse((cnt=length(which(d>0)))>0,cnt,1),by=key(df)]
```

Note that looping is not recommended here. 
And best strategy is to vectorize the solution, as in the example above.

Step3: Lets test for timing:

```
> dt<-df
> for(i in 1:20) dt <- rbind(dt,dt)
> dim(dt)
[1] 9437184       4
> setkey(dt,a,b,c)
> dt[,sum(d)/ifelse((cnt=length(which(d>0)))>0,cnt,1),by=key(dt)]
   a b c  V1
1: 1 1 1 250
2: 1 1 2 600
3: 1 2 3 150
4: 1 3 1   0
> system.time(dt[,sum(d)/ifelse((cnt=length(which(d>0)))>0,cnt,1),by=key(dt)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.495   0.090   0.609
```

So the computation for nearly 10M records is performed in about 0.5 sec!

Hope this helps!!

Comment: two comments - it's not fair to set the key and then leave that out of your timing (not a huge deal, since setting the key doesn't change the speed by too much, but still), and see my comment in the other `data.table` answer for a simpler way of doing what you did

Comment: Thanks @eddi. On the first point: I was trying to illustrate the speed of execution, and as setting the key didn't take much time, so I didn't include it. However, I noticed an important thing here, the 20 fold `rbind` on `dt` runs much faster in comparison to the 20 fold `rbind` on `df`. Any comments on that??
Second point is very well taken and really appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what to comment except that the `data.table` `rbind` is just better :) It uses `rbindlist` internally, which is really fast.